# FOS User Bundle using parameters from ORM Database

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOS User Bundle and I need to use a value called "maxLoginAttempts" from a record of another Entity/table that I use for my parameters.

The Entity it's called Parameters. This is my current code and I would like to change the number 5 for the value from database.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    ...

    public function isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        if($this->getLoginAttempts() >= 5) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
     }
 }
```

I imagine something like:

```
  $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Parameters')
        ->findOneBy(['name' => 'maxLoginAttempts']);
```

Obviously right now I don't have access to the repository. As I'm not in the Controller I'm not sure how I should use these values from inside a function of an Entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the solution was to override the UserChecker using another functions with the same functionality.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Checker;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CredentialsExpiredException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\DisabledException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\LockedException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserChecker as BaseUserChecker;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class UserChecker extends BaseUserChecker
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct( EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function checkPreAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {
        //parent::checkPreAuth($user);
        $maxMinutesLocked = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Parameters')->findOneBy(array('name' => 'maxTimeLocked'))->getValue();

        if (!$user instanceof AdvancedUserInterface) {
            return;
        }

        //So I just added a new function called isAccountLocked() to the User Entity that's a copy from isAccountNonLocked() but I could add a paramater
        if ($user->isAccountLocked($maxMinutesLocked)) {
            $ex = new LockedException('User account is locked.');
            $ex->setUser($user);
            throw $ex;
        }

        if (!$user->isEnabled()) {
            ...
        }
        if (!$user->isAccountNonExpired()) {
            ...
        }
    }

    public function checkPostAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably misunderstands the concept of an [Entity](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html):

> The class - often called an "entity", meaning a basic class that holds data - is simple and helps fulfill the business requirement of needing products in your application. This class can't be persisted to a database yet - it's just a simple PHP class

That means that the `Entity` is just the **concept**, thus you can't have an access to the other `Entities` or to the `EntityManager` from inside the class.

If you want to use something like that member function you've described. you should pass `maxLoginAttempts` as an arg:

```
public function isAccountNonLocked($maxLoginAttempts)
{
    if($this->getLoginAttempts() >= maxLoginAttempts) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

In this case you need to get the value of `maxLoginAttempts` from your config `Entity` first and then use it on the **object** of the `User` you want to check:

```
$maxLoginAttempts = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Parameters')
        ->findOneBy(['name' => 'maxLoginAttempts']);
$user = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->find($userId);
if ($user->isAccountNonLocked($maxLoginAttempts)) {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: Did you realized that this function is used inside the Security Core of Symfony and also inside the FOSUserBundle? I'm not sure but I think it's not so easy as you said. I would like to know another answer please.

Comment: You won't be able to do anything in the base class that is for sure. I supposed you've overridden this method in yours `User` class. Don't you have one?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a more proper way, IMHO, to solve this:

The User entity will have an additional property *$loginAttempts* that will be incremented by the incrementLoginAttempts() method each time the login fails. Its will be initialized to 0 through the ORM and a method isLocked() will tell us if we've reached 5 attempts.

```
<?php
// AppBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /** 
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer",options={"default"=0}) 
     */
    private $loginAttempts;

    ...
    public function getLoginAttempts()
    {
       return $this->loginAttemps;
    }
    public function incrementLoginAttempts()
    {
       if($this->loginAttempts<5){
             $this->loginAttempts++;
       }
       return $this;
    }
    public function isLocked()
    {
        return ($this->loginAttempts == 5)
    }
    public function resetLoginAttempts()
    {
        $this->loginAttempts =0;
        return $this;
    }
```

Then, create an [EventSubscriber](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) to the SecuritySubscriber event, and fire an incrementLoginAttempts() each time the login fails; at the same time check if the user has already been locked or not yet

```
    <?php
// src/AppBundle/EventSubscriber/SecuritySubscriber.php
namespace AppBundle\EventSubscriber;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;  

class SecuritySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface  
{

    private $entityManager;
    private $tokenStorage;
    private $authenticationUtils;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager, TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage, AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->authenticationUtils = $authenticationUtils;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            AuthenticationEvents::AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE => 'onAuthenticationFailure',
        );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure( AuthenticationFailureEvent $event )
    {
        $existingUser = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['username' => $username]);

        if ($existingUser) {
            $existingUser->incrementLoginAttempts();
            $this->entityManager->persist($existingUser);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
            if($existingUser->isLocked()){
                // Do your logic here
                // Do not forget to un  $existingUser->resetLoginAttempts() when necessary
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to register the subscriber as a service

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:  
    app.security.authentication_event_listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventSubscriber\SecuritySubscriber
        arguments:
            - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
            - "@security.token_storage"
            - "@security.authentication_utils"
```

P.S: The code has not been tested.

Comment: FOSUserBundle do that for me. Right now I can control all the functionality of the isAccountNonLocked() that provides FOSUSerBundle. After 5 failed login the account is locked for a time I provide (for example 1 hour). But my question is not to build this functionality or to fix it.

The problem is that I want to get that number 5 from a table of bbdd called in this case Parameters. I want to replace this number 5 for a variable to be able to change the value from the database and not from the code.

Comment: In your place, I would put this in parameters.yml as a config variable then load and use it as described here https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/best_practices/configuration.html

If you insist on db-persisted values, you have two choices depending on how you've implemented your logic:
1- Either you access entityManager from the controller and pass the maxLoginAttemtps as an argument to the User entity method
2- Or you define you FOSUser login form as a service and inject entityManager in it then use it to pass the maxLoginAttemtps to the User Entity